# How to redirect to reverse tunnel server with different port?

Tags: server, ssh

**Setup:**
Server A ( Hosted in private network, need VPN access )
Server B ( Public hosted )
Server C ( U can assume is my own macbook )

I use `autossh` to setup my reverse tunneling at server A
with this command `autossh -f -T -M 20002 -o "ServerAliveInterval 10" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 2" -N -R 19999:localhost:22 user@server_b`

Then in my Server B
I able to run `ssh localhost -p 199999` to connect my server A.
Server B also enabled ssh port for `22` and `2022` at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

**Problem statement:**
How do I use command `ssh user@server_b -p 2022` at **Server C** to redirect access the **Server A** tunnel from **Server B**?

**Big picture**
macbook -- ssh ( port 2022 ) --> server B -- redirect ssh ---> Server A

**must able to do scp task

Comment: Hello, could you specify where is Ubuntu in your setup and what version you have?

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen ubuntu 20

Comment: All 3 servers are running Ubuntu?

Comment: Server A and Server B is ubuntu 20.. Server C is just an example.. Server C is my starting point to connect the Server A.. Server C is unix base ( macbook )

Answer (score 2):

1. To use a reverse tunnel automatically it is recommended to use `autossh` service.
2. I recommend to follow those steps:
3. Change keys between the servers you want to tunnel.

   - save your server A public_key on your server B `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.
   - make the first connection manually with `ssh user@serverB` and see the connection is working fine.
   - do the same with server C - save your server B public_key on your server C `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.
   - check the connection manually.
4. Now you have to redirect the ports you want with `autossh` - but first lets check that manually:

   - connect to your A server from your local pc with `ssh user@serverA`
   - on your server A shell - port forward the `ssh` connection from server A to server B with `ssh -R <portX>:localhost:22 user@serverB`
   - **on your server B shell** - port forward the **serverA** `ssh` tunnel with `ssh -R <portY>:localhost:<portX> user@serverC`.
   - now open another terminal on your local pc (without closing the existing terminal) and try to use the redirected tunnel with `ssh user@serverC -p <portY>` this should connect you to server A through servers C and B in the specific order.
5. Now after the tunnel seems to work fine we can automate the process by creating an `autossh` service (here is the one i am using):

```
[Unit]
Description=Keeps a tunnel to 'VPS' open
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/autossh -M portZ -i /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 -o "ExitOnForwardFaliure=yes" -o "ServerAliveInterval 30" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -N -R portX:127.0.0.1:22 root@X.X.X.X 
Environment=AUTOSSH_GATETIME=0
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
StartLimitAction=reboot
StartLimitBurst=0
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Now if you want to copy something into your computer with `scp` from server A just run the command on your local pc terminal:**

- `scp -P <portY> user@serverC:/path/path/filename localpcpath/path/.`

**Note: my answer assume that you have already created `ssh keys` and that your `sshd_config` file is configured well.**